# CouchDB Slow performace in Test Suite

Tags: couchdb

I have a new server running Centos 6 with 6 cores and 16 GB RAM, etc..

In this server I only install CouchDB, following the install instructions in:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_RHEL5

I run the Test Suite and is extremly slow, for example "basics" in 30,000ms

I see in the book "CouchDB: The Definitive Guide", (page 24) the same test in 652ms !!

What I'am doing wrong ??